# Laravel wkhtmltopdf - text in the bottom of the last page

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, laravel-snappy

I'm generating an invoice PDF using [laravel snappy wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) 
and I'm tring to add some text in the bottom of the last page,
now i already have a footer-html with the number of the page.

I tried to show the content only in the last page with this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="footer_text">
     {!! nl2br($footer_text) !!}
</div>
<div class="pagination"><span id='page'></span> of <span id='topage'></span></div>
<script> 

    function remove(id) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(id);
        return elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }

    var vars={};
    var x=window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
    for (var i in x) {
        var z=x[i].split('=',2);
        vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);
    }

    document.getElementById('page').innerHTML = vars.page; 
    document.getElementById('topage').innerHTML = vars.topage; 

    if( vars.page != vars.topage && vars.topage > 1){
        document.getElementById('footer_text').innerHTML = '';
        remove('footer_text');
    }

    if(vars.topage == 1){
        document.getElementById('pages').innerHTML = '';
    }

</script>
```

and it does show me the text only in the last page **BUT** in the previous pages I have a big white space, here is a screenshot:

page number 1:
[image]

page number 2:
[image]

I feel like i tried everything, please help me

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your script it might be some style issue. As you are removing `footer_text` in all previous pages and showing only on last page and this is somehow creating too much space. Check your CSS there must be margin-bottom or padding-bottom which is creating too much space. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but looks like the ID footer_text will be set multiple times and ID's should be unique so I guess it would have worked if you used a class instead and `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0):

The footer height can't be dynamic on a different page when using Wkhtmltopdf. It's always with a static height. If this is your footer.html you have to add to your style:

body {height: 70px /*for example*/; position: relative;}

so you can align bottom (with position:absolute; bottom:0;) you #footer_text and content. But still, have some white space on all prev pages.
In the PDF generators, the footer content area is independent of the body content.